# Filtering pandas DataFrame based on row non-zero values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas df like the following:

```
date X1 X2 X3  Y  user
1/1   0  3 34  5   a
2/1   0  7 65  5   a
3/1   0 13  0  5   a
4/1  25  4 65  0   a
5/1  35  0  0  5   a
6/1   4  6  9  0   a
7/1   0  0  0  5   a
1/1   0  0 34  5   b
2/1   0  7 65  5   b
3/1   0 13  0  5   b
4/1   0  4 65  5   b
5/1  35  0  0  5   b
6/1   4  6  9  0   b
7/1   0  0  0  0   b
```

How can I use select rows per `user` only after all `Xs` start appearing non-zero values, using `groupby()` . In that case, select only rows for `dates` `4/1`,`5/1`,`6/1`,`7/1` for user `a` and `dates` `6/1`,`7/1` for user `b`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
df.groupby('user') \
  .apply(lambda s: s[s.filter(like='X').ne(0).all(1).cumsum().ge(1)]))
```

---

```
        date  X1  X2  X3  Y user
user                            
a    3   4/1  25   4  65  0    a
     4   5/1  35   0   0  5    a
     5   6/1   4   6   9  0    a
     6   7/1   0   0   0  5    a
b    12  6/1   4   6   9  0    b
     13  7/1   0   0   0  0    b
```

Comment: `5/1` for `b` should not be included since only his `X1` is non-zero. ALL his `Xs` should be non-zero, hence `6/1` and `7/1` should only be collected.

Comment: Gotcha. My answer has been updated

Comment: How would you change your answer if the condition change from `non-zero` to `greater than zero` values, again for all `Xs` ?? Thanks

Comment: If it doesn't already.

Comment: @Telis change from `.ne(0)` to `.ge(0)`

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution would be to use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) with [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
#are all the `X`s not equal to 0 ?
m = df.filter(like="X").ne(0).all(axis=1)
​
out = df.loc[m.groupby(df["user"]).cummax()]
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

   date  X1  X2  X3  Y user
3   4/1  25   4  65  0    a
4   5/1  35   0   0  5    a
5   6/1   4   6   9  0    a
6   7/1   0   0   0  5    a
12  6/1   4   6   9  0    b
13  7/1   0   0   0  0    b
```

Comment: How would you change your answer if the condition change from `non-zero` to `greater than zero` values, again for all Xs ?? Thanks